# How can mouse support be enabled in terminal Emacs?

Tags: terminal, emacs, mouse

How can mouse support be enabled in an Emacs terminal session started with `emacs -nw`? Is there a keyboard shortcut or a flag to do this? If not how can it be done in terminal emulators? I use Guake.

Comment: Are you running `emacs` in a GUI terminal emulator? What kind of support do you need? Placing the cursor? Copy/pasting?

Comment: [Emacs: Using a Mouse in Text Terminals](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Text_002dOnly-Mouse.html)

Comment: @terdon I am using guake.

Comment: OK, please [edit] your question and add that information. Also explain exactly what type of mouse support you need.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick that should be an answer. It's probably precisely what the OP needs.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick sorry I am new to emacs when I hit alt+x it goes in the bottom bar how do I run the command? Enter returns `' is not a valid command name

Comment: @user Type ALT-X, then `xterm-mouse-mode`, then return.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick IANAL but I really doubt there could be any licencing issue when quoting from an oficial manual!

Comment: @MarkPlotnick it worked

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Hit <kbd>F10</kbd> to open the menu and use the arrow keys to navigate to “Options” → “Customize Emacs” → “All Settings Matching…”. Type `mouse` and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If your Emacs version doesn't have a menu when running in a terminal then run `M-x customize`. (This means: press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, type `customize` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.) Navigate to the search box, type `mouse` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Mouse support is called “Xterm Mouse mode”. You can find that in the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Text_002dOnly-Mouse.html). The manual also gives a way to turn it on (for the current session) — `M-x xterm-mouse-mode`.

In the Customize interface, on the setting you want to change, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on “Show Value”. A “Toggle” button appears, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on it. Then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the “State” box and choose either `0` for “Set for Current Session” or “1” for “Save for Future Sessions”. (You can choose `0` for now and come back there and choose `1` later if you're happy with the setting.)

Answer (score 29):

add `(xterm-mouse-mode 1)` to your `~/.emacs.d/init.el` file.

Comment: Thanks! I was searching for that as my customizations menu is empty (I compiled it from the git sources, works well so far, so I'm happy with that)